# Django list object in model does not persist in session after server restart

Tags: django, list, session, model, persistence

Ok so i will start off with what my code is:

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
order_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
order_status = models.IntegerField()
orderItems = []
```

views.py

```
def addToList(request):
   prodId = request.GET['prodId'] or None
   if not prodId is None:
      prod = Product.objects.get(prod_id=prodId)
      custOrder = request.session.get(definitions.CUSTOMER_ORDER) or \
                Order(order_total = 0, order_status=1)
    custOrder.addOrderItem(prod)
    request.session[definitions.CUSTOMER_ORDER] = custOrder

return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


def home(request):
    shoppingList = request.session.get(definitions.CUSTOMER_ORDER)
```

Ok so as you can see I create the Order Model and then add an orderItem to the list that's in that model and store it in the session. Now this works fine and the data persists as expected. Thing is when I restart the server the Order model is still in the session which is what I want but the list object is **EMPTY**. orderItems = [] when I debug it.

Now I am not a python guru so if anyone could point out what I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Adding orderItem Model for models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
orderItem_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
orderItem_cost = models.FloatField()
orderItem_quantity = models.IntegerField()
order = models.ForeignKey(Order)

def getOrderCost(self):
    return self.orderItem_cost * self.orderItem_quantity

class Meta:
    db_table = u'orderItems'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not persisting `orderItems` in the database, it's just a list attribute in the `Order` object. You can rework the models, like have a `ManyToManyField` with `Product`s in `Order`.

[ManyToMany examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Would be nice to have a small example here. Not just a link (which may be deleted or unreachable)

Comment: It's a link to the official documentation

Comment: @msc: Are you saying that for models to persist in a session like that all the attributes need to be database fields?